# Are there typescript compiler options outside the tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, npm, typescript-typings

### Problem

Until a certain point in time my app compiled and ran in the browser just fine. Then I installed and uninstalled [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) and [npm's @types/*](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/consumption.html). After that my original app wasn't compiling anymore without errors, although the code and `tsconfig.json` are unchanged.

### Question

What am I missing here? Why is the TS compiler suddenly behaving differently?

### Details

1. After compiling the original code successfully I installed [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings).
2. I installed a definition using `typings install dt~amodule --global --save`
3. I then installed an [npm based solution](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/consumption.html) for missing type definitions: `npm install --save-dev amodule`
4. I modified the code to use the npm-definition
5. I reverted everything with git and by hand. Especially I removed the `typings` folder. `npm uninstall`ed the `@types/amodule` and the global `typings`.
6. Now errors are popping up in components and libraries I didn't even touch during the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Cause

The Problem was that `typescript` was installed by npm from the `package.json` with a non-fixed version, like:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^2.1.5"
}
```

when using `npm install` the typescript version of the project updated without me noticing.

### Solution

Freezing the typescript version and rerunning `npm install` solved the problem.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "2.1.5"
}
```